# Undefined variable error in theme option after updating theme

Tags: themes, debug

I have built a theme.. Now i have updated the theme and my theme consist of two new fields in the theme option panel

```
<input id="welcome_post_char" type="text" name="abc_options[welcome_post_char]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($settings['welcome_post_char'],'abc'); ?>">
```

But when i install this theme with old abc_options in my database table, gives an error

> Undefined index: welcome_post_char in D:\wamp\www\wptest2\wp-content\themes\accesspress-lite\inc\admin-panel\theme-options.php on line 394

If i do

```
<input id="welcome_post_char" type="text" name="abc_options[welcome_post_char]" value="<?php if (isset($settings['welcome_post_char'])){echo esc_attr($settings['welcome_post_char'],'abc')}; ?>">
```

it doesn't give errors..
But i didn't see this approach in other Themes..
So can anyone please suggest me what is the best approach

Comment: This is not really related to wordpress, but php, which is off topic here.

Comment: If you could answer then please...
and It is related to wordpress Theme development

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with this pieter.. Instead of answer what is he doing.. He can use his time instead answering the question

Comment: I understand and appreciate your concern, but there are community rules that we all need to abide by to keep this site constructive. Unfortunately your question doesn't fall into scope as this is purely a php error. [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is more suited for this type of questions as it is dedicated to php

Answer (score 1):

@pzstar it is a good approach to check if your variables are assigned a value or not. If a variable or an index in an array is not declared/assigned then you'd probably get such error.
 I would suggest you to use isset().

```
<input id="welcome_post_char" type="text" name="abc_options[welcome_post_char]" value="<?php echo (isset($settings['welcome_post_char']))? esc_attr($settings['welcome_post_char'],'abc'): ''}; ?>">
```